# How do i check options in a Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
$.fn.newContent = function(options) {
var defaults = {
  name: "newContent",
  actionBar: "true"
};
  var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);
  var newElem =  $("<div class='contents'></div>");
};
```

I would like to add a `span` element to the `div` with `id` contents, if and only if the `actionBar` option is true. I cannot seem to get the code to make it right. I tried :

```
var isActionBar = defaults.actionBar;
```

but it does not work. Please is there any problem with my code?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work," do you mean that `isActionBar` doesn't contain anything?  Seems like all you're really doing there is creating a reference variable, so if `defaults.actionBar` doesn't contain anything, neither will `isActionBar`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `settings.actionBar` ?

Comment: Why is `defaults.actionBar` receiving a string of `"true"` instead of a Boolean `true`?

Comment: It is accepting a boolean but i want a string

Comment: @Delali: Why do you want a string when it's clearly a boolean operation?

Comment: Oh! sorry guys. The string i wanted was true but i forgot that it was a Boolean operation. I tried using another string for the actionBar options and it worked. Thanks @Robert

Comment: @Delali `defaults.actionBar` should be boolean, not a string. So try `var default = {actionBar: true}` and use plugin as `$('.some').newContent({actionBar: false})`.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks so much, but `defaults.actionBar` can also accept strings. It worked in my code.

Comment: I'm not trying to belabour the point, but when you say "it worked in my code," this is in reference to the code that you say (without any clarification) "does not work"? Or am I missing something?